# 3d Shape fill connects to first vertex on P5.js webGL

Tags: 3d, webgl, p5.js, vertex

### **This is the effect I'm trying to achieve**

This is done using processing 3.x

I'm trying to recreate the same effect using p5.js
https://editor.p5js.org/atommic/sketches/kqblWtqln

[image: This is the effect I'm trying to achieve (done with Processing 3.x)]

### **This is what it looks like on p5.js when all vertexes have the same z value**

When all vertexes are on the same plane there is no issue and it looks as expected

[image: P5.js sketch - completely 2d - all vertexes are on the same plane]

the X and Y values of this shape are 2 arrays.
The Z value is a function of mouseX.

```
for (var i = 0; i < xpos0.length; i++) {

    G = abs((xpos0[i] - mouseX+500)) / (80);
    if (G >= 1) {
        G = 1;
    }
    curveY = curvePoint(-5, 15, 0, 20, G);

    vertex(xpos0[i], ypos0[i], -curveY);  
}
```

### **This is what it looks like on P5.js when using different z values**

When moving the mouse and changing the Z value of some of the vertexes, this effect happens.
The fill somehow connects everything to the first vertex of the array

[image: P5.js - vertexes are on different planes, fill connects to first vertex]
[image: P5.js - vertexes are on different planes - connection to first vertex is more visible]

Any idea why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue as it is described as expected behavior in p5js documentation

https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/vertex
[image]

Comment: Maybe I can insterest you in three.js ;) :)

Comment: I was thinking about three.js for that.
Any chance you might have a sample I can start from for this scenario?

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ShapeGeometry I believe this is useful, you can almost port it straight over.. It will even run faster I think. In your example you're drawing the shape every frame in draw, with the shapeGeometry you can initialize it once and modify the z positions every frame.

Comment: I made a small example, with the first 2 vertices moving up and down to show how to move them: https://jsfiddle.net/EthanHermsey/nwo13vys/47/